# Compression level of netCDF4 variable

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

How do you determine the compression level of a netCDF4 variable (preferably in Python)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python option using netCDF4 directly:

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
ds = nc4.Dataset('foo.nc')
var = ds.variables['bar']
print('complevel: %s', var.filters().get('complevel', False))
```

*Note that the `filters` method returns a dictionary of all the HDF5 filter parameters*

Python option using Xarray and netCDF4 under the hood:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('foo.nc')
print('complevel: %s', ds['bar'].encoding.get('complevel', False))
```

*Note that the encoding attribute is a dictionary with all the variable encoding attributes for each variable*

The command line options is easy too:

```
ncdump -h -s foo.nc
```